# How to add -moz & -o prefixes to code containing only -webkit tags

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

Say, I have this page: http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html

I save the page & run the html file in my localhost. It works fine in chrome as the css uses -webkit prefix. Now I want to test whether is runs on firefox & opera too. So I have to add a -moz & -o prefix in the same css code which has -webkit.

Is there any other method rather than appending -moz & -o prefixes myself in the code? 
One method is writing a script to read the file & append the tags. Any others?

**Note:** I am not concerned about whether the css3 transforms used by -webkit are currently supported by -moz or -o or not. All I want is how to duplicate the -webkit lines, adding -moz & -o vendor prefixes to them.

Comment: So you do **not** want a script that appends `-moz` and `-o`?

Comment: @Abody97 Am too lazy to write one. :P
Well if one exists, it is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be **vendor prefix** JS helps you http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

Comment: Nice one! This will help. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have ONE, You have many..

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/

I like [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)